# Safari/Chrome does not understand jQuery focus/blur on check boxes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css-selectors, haml

Here's my javascript:

```
$(".more_info").hide();
$(".checkbox.has_info, .has_info").focus(function(){
  $(this).parent().next().next().show("fast");
});
$(".checkbox.has_info, .has_info").blur(function(){
  $(this).parent().next().next().hide("fast");
});
```

Note, that this works perfectly in Firefox/ IE7, IE8.

So far I have discovered that this is because Safari and Chrome do not accept the focus/blur events for check box or radio buttons. Anyone know a work around that still has the same effect?

Comment: That's not your HTML, that's your ruby markup :) Make sure to post the actual HTML.

Comment: I removed it because it was unneccessary, and simplified my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Here it is folks! Amazing!

```
$(".more_info").hide();

var $info_items = jQuery('.checkbox.has_info, .has_info')
$info_items.click(function(){
  var $info_item = jQuery(this);
  $info_items.filter(function(index){
    return $(".hidden_text").css("display","block");
    }).not($info_item).parent().next().next().hide("slow");
  $info_item.parent().next().next().show("fast");
});
```